# Margin paragraph and head rule are reversed on even pages in twoside book

Tags: fancyhdr, double-sided, marginpar, hebrew

I am writing a book in Hebrew (which means Right to Left direction of text) using the `book` doc class together with the `twoside` option.

I enlarged the margin paragraph to be `50mm`. Now I want the header rule to overhang the outside margin. I followed the example in section 18 of the fancyhdr manual:

```
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
```

That works fine on English documents, but this is the output I get for the even pages in my (Hebrew) document:

[image]

Besides, the margin paragraph is reversed, for some reason.

How do I fix these two things?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
%%% Page layout
\geometry{%
asymmetric,
left=70mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8mm,
marginparwidth=50mm,

}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase , Ligatures =TeX}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\chapter{הקדמה}
\begin{english}
\lipsum[1-5]\marginpar{Some margin note goes here}
\lipsum[6-10]\marginpar{Another margin note goes here}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `twoside` and `asymmetric` options seem to be conflicting, and as `twoside` is default for the `book` class, `oneside` must be explicitly given as document class option.
2. Both `geometry` and `fancyhdr` get confused about left/right in the Hebrew text apparently, so we have to use the opposite: `right=70mm` instead of `left=70mm`. And for `fancyhdr` see below.
3. Instead of calculating `\headwidth`, use `\fancyhfoffset`, but we have to use `R` instead of `L`, although the offset is on the left.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
%%% Page layout
\geometry{%
asymmetric,
right=70mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8mm,
marginparwidth=50mm,
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
% \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\usepackage{calc}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase , Ligatures =TeX}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\chapter{הקדמ}
\begin{english}
\lipsum[1-5]\marginpar{Some margin note goes here}
\lipsum[6-10]\marginpar{Another margin note goes here}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The output I get from your MWE is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZVBx.jpg) (I checked it both on my TeXLive '21 and on overleaf.com, same output). I think that you need to change the `R` in `\fancyhfoffset[R]{..}` to `L`. Besides that, I want the body text to be on the right side of the page, and the margin paragraph to be to its left (as it is in my image on the original post). So, as I see it, since the margin paragraph alternates its position, the matter of how to control where it is printed should be asked in a different question.

Comment: Your solution indeed works. The alternating placement of the marginal notes is probably due to the `\begin{english}..\end{english}` environment. With Hebrew Lorem Ipsum text it works fine.